# Convert VARCHAR to Time in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, types

I am using `ORACLE` and I want to convert `VARCHAR` type into Time using following SQL Query

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_SERVICE_QUOTE_MEAS.ITEM_CREATE_TM,
TO_char(
CUSTOMER_SERVICE_QUOTE_MEAS.ITEM_CREATE_TM,
'hh24:mi:ss')
AS TIME_CHANGE
FROM FDC.CUSTOMER_SERVICE_QUOTE_MEAS CUSTOMER_SERVICE_QUOTE_MEAS
```

This results in `6/1/2013 11:32:02 AM` but I don't want the date part here.
 I need only time portion `11:32:02`, How it can be done ?

The field `CUSTOMER_SERVICE_QUOTE_MEAS.ITEM_CREATE_TM` has the data which look like this `113202`.
Any help will be appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don't format code as quote: format is as code, so we can have goodies like syntax highlighting and whitespace. I've done it for you this time.

Comment: It's impossible that your code returns the output you claim. It's possibly triggering a `ORA-01481: invalid number format model` error.

Answer (score 8):

Is the datatype of the item_create_tm column a NUMBER? The to_char is expecting a date column. To replicate the error:

```
SELECT to_char(113202, 'hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;
```

It generates this error.

```
ORA-01481: invalid number format model
01481. 00000 -  "invalid number format model"
*Cause:    The user is attempting to either convert a number to a string
           via TO_CHAR or a string to a number via TO_NUMBER and has
           supplied an invalid number format model parameter.
*Action:   Consult your manual.
```

You could either transform it to a date first and then to a formatted char.

```
SELECT to_char(to_date(113202, 'hh24miss'), 'hh24:mi:ss') FROM dual;
```

Output

```
11:32:02
```

Or substring the number to a char with : separators.

```
SELECT substr(113202, 1, 2) || ':' || substr(113202, 3, 2) || ':' || substr(113202, 5, 2) FROM dual;
```

Output

```
11:32:02
```

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap dates with to_char and a format something like this:

```
select to_char( mydate, 'hh24:mi:ss' ) as mytime from mytable;
```

Comment: Thanks Randy but i get this error. ORA-01481: invalid number format model.

Comment: Randy. could you please throw some light on the above issue please.

Comment: `TO_CHAR()` expects a number or date, not a string.